# In the Here API for Navigation / Routing API how is BaseTime calculated?

Tags: here-api

In RouteSummaryType response https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-type-route-summary.html

A field "BaseTime" is provided "Contains the travel time estimate in seconds for this element, considering transport mode but not traffic conditions"

How is that calculated and is it an average, a median a 95%-ile number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base-time is based on free-flow speeds for a link. This is a speed derived from historic traffic based speeds on the link, but not live traffic conditions. The exact calculation logic is not exposed to freemium customers. If you are a premium customer you can contact your sales representative to get detailed information.

Comment: Awesome - many thanks for the information. Do premium customers get live traffic conditions?